# SQL Command.ExecuteReader vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to use a login form with SQL Express 2012 and vb.net. I have the db connection, now I have the following problem;
Incorrect syntax near '=' for the code ; data = command.ExecuteReader
Any suggestions? Here is the code
Thanks!!!!!!!

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb


Public Class login
Private Sub login_user_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles login_user.Click
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.ConnectionString = ("Server=192.168.0.2;Database=Sunshinetix;User=sa;Password=sunshine;")
    End If

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT = FROM Users Where Username = '" & username_user.Text & "';"
        Dim data As SqlDataReader
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim command As New SqlCommand
        command.CommandText = sqlquery
        command.Connection = conn
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        data = command.ExecuteReader()
        While data.Read
            If data.HasRows = True Then
                If data(2).ToString = password_user.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Sucsess")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Login Failed! Please try again or contact support")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Login Failed! Please try again or contact support")
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `SELECT = FROM` is incorrect syntax. It should either be `SELECT * FROM` or (more likely) `SELECT Some_specific_field FROM`

Comment: [In 2013, SQL Injection was rated the number one attack on the OWASP top ten.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was that your query is `SELECT = FROM` which is obviously a typo the correct syntax is `SELECT * FROM`.

See my code to avoid `SqlInjection`

[image]

Try this code:

```
 Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.ConnectionString = ("Server=192.168.0.2;Database=Sunshinetix;User=sa;Password=sunshine;")
    End If

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM Users Where Username = @user;"

        Dim data As SqlDataReader
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim parameter As New SqlParameter
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)
        With command.Parameters
            .Add(New SqlParameter("@user", password_user.Text))
        End With
        command.Connection = conn
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        data = command.ExecuteReader()
        While data.Read
            If data.HasRows = True Then
                If data(2).ToString = password_user.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Sucsess")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Login Failed! Please try again or contact support")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Login Failed! Please try again or contact support")
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

I would recommend to you use the parametrized query to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: when i changed the code, i got the same error as i started with. yours does make more sence, but it still doesnt work?

Comment: What error/exception do you get and where?

Comment: it brings be back to the top at private sub and says "Incorrect Syntax near '='.' A system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception was caught: "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Comment: it also wont let me put ; after my code? I think that is a C# thing? I am a beginner...

Comment: try my edit, This thing is sql query, and every query should be terminated with `;`

Comment: i added my screenshot so you can see what i see. the character not valid is referring to **;**

Comment: @user3232927 post the image url in comment, edit isnt used for commenting.

Comment: sorry about that. here is the link   http://www.4shared.com/download/NCtTpKWcce/vb_error.jpg

Comment: delete this line of code `SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();` and delete the `;` after the statements, sorry for that Im used from c# and change `Dim parameter As New SqlParameter();` to  `Dim parameter As New SqlParameter`

Comment: not a problem, thats what i figured. no errors before debug, but same syntax error

Comment: i had to remove ` = New SqlCommand` for visual basic not to error. My line says `Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)` , but still same syntax error

Comment: If not my last edit works Can you post actual image of that ?

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/download/1Ll-BU0Lba/vb_error.jpg

Comment: Ok, try my last edit.

Comment: everything is the same as my screenshot except the dim command line?

Comment: Yes, use this  `Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM akce Where Username = @user;"`

Comment: but i wouldnt want to change my table name if that is not the table i am pulling from? do you have skype?

Comment: lets use teamviewer. post id and pass.

Answer (score 6):

Change

`SELECT = FROM Users ....`

to

`SELECT * FROM Users ....`

Answer (score 0):

There is an Extra `=` in your query, There should not be any = after Select keyword.

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM Users Where Username = '" & username_user.Text & "';"
```